# iphone navigation application with tabbar-like menu at the bottom

Tags: iphone, menu, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I have a navigation based application. In the main screen it has 5 buttons and according to which one is pressed then we move using the navigation controller. What I want is that in the rest Views (except the main screen) to have a tabbar-like menu with 5 buttons each one doing the same as the ones in the main screen (pushing that view). Is there any library to create such a menu or I will have to create it by mySelf?

-If I do it myself and lets say I create a nib with 60px height, how do I add this nib in each nib of my other views so as to make the right design? (this is a noob question sorry, but until now I have only added generic iphone components :) ).

Comment: So after Main navigation controller you don't want to use tabbarcontroller but instead of this you want some buttons say 5 buttons which will work as 5 independent viewcontroller?

Comment: @dh14-sl I want something like a toolBar with 5 buttons that each one pushes in the current navigation controller another view. It is not a tab view, since all these buttons actually push the same view with different data.

Comment: @waheeda I think this is the one I want! Thanks, I will try it out.

Comment: @waheeda This was the way!! Thanks a lot. I made a subclass of UITableViewController, I added the button selectors methods, and prepared the UIToolbar (navigation controller has UIToolBar embedded). Then all my tableviewVCs are subclassed of that class so they intantly inherit the UIToolbar.